# JQuery button style works in navbar, but not in table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have used the exact same code in the navbar as in the table but it doesn't seem to work.

I am using js/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js and Phonegap (Cordova)

Below is a screenshot of the what happens:

[image]

I am using this html code to create the navbar button:

```
<div data-role="header">
    <a href="." data-icon="back" class="back ui-btn-left" data-rel="back">Back</a>
    <h1>Conversion List</h1>
</div>
```

To generate the button in the table I am using JavaScript which loops over each of the values in a local database table and prints the values in the screen html table.

I have the html code:

```
<div data-role="content">
<!--table which outputs the conversions stored in the database-->
    <table id="viewConversions"width="100%"text-align="center" >
    </table>
    </br>
    <a href="#drugs" data-role="button" id="btnlist">Add new conversion</a>
</div>
```

and the JavaScript code:

```
$('#viewConversions').append('<tr><td>'+drug+'</td><td>'+route+'</td><td>'+ conversion +'</td><td>' +output+'</td><td><a href="" id="' + cid + '"data-icon="back" class="back ui-btn-left" data-rel="back"</a>Back</td></tr>');
```

Does the JQuery extension not work in tables or am I doing something else wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem by adding this piece of code into the JavaScript:

```
data-role="button"
```

This allows the jquery to realize it is a button.

Then below the JavaScript line I have:

```
$("#conversionlist").trigger('pagecreate');
$("#viewConversion").listview("refresh");
```

Answer (score 1):

This will trigger pagecreate

```
$('#page-id').trigger('pagecreate');
```

Comment: This just changes the colour of the font to blue

Comment: Give the same attributes to the button in table as the one on the top

Comment: Ok fine. Glad to help you. Please choose this as the answer if your problem is solved